# spray.json.DeserializationException: Expected String as JsString, but got {}

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json, either

I am using Either implementation for my object because I am expecting an empty Json for one of the parameter in the object. Here is the object:

```
case class Record(id: String, version: Long, payload: Either[PayloadObject, String]))
```

I am trying to unit test this sending an empty json string which is like this:

```
val jsonString = """
     | {
     |   "id":"someId"
     |   "version":123456
     |   "payload":{}
     | }
|""".stripMargin
```

This is my unit test where I am deserializing the above json String:

```
{
val deserialized = Record("someId", 123456L, Right(""))
val result = jsonString.convertTo[Record]
result must equal(deserialized)
}
```

This is throwing error. spray.json.DeserializationException: Expected String as JsString, but got {}. How to represent the variable `serialized` as an empty JsString to run the unit tests? Thanks

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: Sidenote: the JSON is the serialized form. Here you are testing deserialization: converting JSON to case class.

Comment: Updated the question. Import is `spray.json._` for serialize-deserialize

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to define a custom format for your case class.

```scala
case class Record(id: String, version: Long, payload: Either[JsObject, String])

object Record {

  implicit val recordFormat: RootJsonReader[Record] = (json: JsValue) =>
    json.asJsObject.getFields("id", "version", "payload") match {
      case Seq(JsString(id), JsNumber(version), JsObject.empty)    => Record(id, version.toLong, Right(""))
      case Seq(JsString(id), JsNumber(version), payload: JsObject) => Record(id, version.toLong, Left(payload))
      case _                                                       => throw new Exception("Invalid record")
    }
}
```